# How to create inputs through text_field_tag helper, without id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have auto-generated text_field_tag inputs, and I don't want `id` attributes there. 
How to do this correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the `id` of the generated text field or any other HTML attribute in the [options attribute](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/text_field_tag) of `text_field_tag`. Setting it to `nil` should remove it completely:

```
text_field_tag('name', nil, id: nil)
```